# When Mongoengine rebuild indexes?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

When Mongoengine rebuild(update) a information about indexes? I mean, if a added or change some field (added uniques or sparse option to filed) or added some meta info in model declaration. 
So question is:

- When mongoengine update it?
- How do they track changes?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9082609/3271558 - I've checked and this is still true as of v  0.9.0

Comment: @SteveRossiter Thanks, mate. But when it will be recreated after deletion? any info? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoengine do not rebuild index automaticly. Mongoengine track changes in models (btw dont work if you add `sparse` to your filed(if field dont have `unique` options)) and then fire the `ensureIndex` in mongoDB. But when its fire - make sure you delete oldest index version manualy(Mongoengine doesn't) in mongoDB.

The problem is:

- if you add `sparse` to filed w.o `unique` option - this changes dont mapped in mongoDB index. You need to combine `unique = True, sparse = True`
- If you change indexs in models - you need to manualy delete old indexes in mongoDB.